# Arrayformula is overwriting the results of the subsequent rows instead of populating their own values

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

The below formula is working

```
=query(INDIRECT(F23&"!A4:G"),"SELECT G WHERE A = '"&Overview!A23&"'")
```

When i convert it to Array formula like this it overwrites the results of next rows.

```
=query(INDIRECT(F23&"!A4:G"),"SELECT G WHERE A = '"&Overview!A23&"'")
```

How can we write array formula for this scenario? Note: Here we are going to different sheets and finding the value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INDIRECT(), does not iterate within ARRAYFORMULAS.  If you want to use Indirect you will have to drag it down.

Comment: @santoshaa  There is a way to "construct" a formula using a combination of text concatenation and scripting, but it is fairly involved.

Comment: I already created the formula / the functionality using script and put it inside onOpen() but i did not know INDIRECT() does not iterate. It would be great to find out why so? Thanks for your answer Matt.